# How to read a PDF up to a certain end line?

Tags: r, regex, pdf-scraping

I am doing for loop for many research papers. Here I want extract from read document a content.

How can I make that R reads only until last line, where many dots are, and indicate as an end-line? like on the picture below:

**[Numbers] [Letter][Dots][Number]**

[image]

If there is no many dots than stop and indicate as an end-line.

For example I have the following code but it doesn't work for other documents, cause sometimes have different endings.

```
if(((nrow(pdf[pdf$text == "References ." & pdf$element_id == '2',]) == 1) & !(exists("endline"))) == 1){

endline <- pdf$line_id[pdf$text == "References ." & pdf$element_id == '2']
   }
```

R reads whole document and identifies only until the last where many dots are.

Comment: Moreover, I also tried this grep() function

 if(nrow(pdf[grep("\\......... ([0-9]{3})$",pdf$text, perl =  TRUE),])){
      endline <-grep("\\......... ([0-9]{3})$",pdf$text, perl =  TRUE)
    }

Comment: Hi @Bakai. Can you please edit your question to add these elements instead of adding a comment? That way, all relevant elements will be directly found in your question.

Comment: Just curious, was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This regex should help:

`(\.+\s*\d+\n)(?!\d)`

Explanation:

`(\.+\s*\d+\n)` - dots and a page number (with optional spaces), followed by an end of line character

`(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead, which means that there are NO digits at the beginning of the next line.

The negative lookahead does the magic of finding the **last** occurrence of the pattern.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/gIrhxf/2